# Can I make a sidebar stick to the left or right side on my screen in HTML and CSS? (Not a navbar)

Tags: html, css

I have two divs.

```html
<div class="sideBarLeft">
...
</div>
<div class="content">
...
</div>
```

and

```css
div.content {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.500);
    padding-left: 250px;
    padding-right: 250px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-right: 250px;
}
div.sideBarLeft {
     overflow: scroll;
     float: left;
}
```

How can I make the sidebar on the left rather than on top?

Comment: hi, can you make a drawing of the complete wanted design please? with the comment son the anwser I believe that you make it more complicated then necessary. YOu proberly would be betetr off with a grid-design if I understand your desired layout right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helloo,

```
div.sideBarLeft {
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

you can try this for navbar on left side

Comment: I have a nav bar at the top and this covers it up. Should I add padding or margin? What could fix this?

Comment: @UCYT5040 you need to increase the z-index of your nav bar at the top so it appears over the sidebar

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark this answer correct as soon as stack overflow allows me to.

Comment: I upped the z index but it didn't change anything.

Comment: if z-index of top navbar is greater than 1 then it should work. You can also try giving inside div.sideBarLeft top: 20px or top: 30px based on the height of your top navbar.